# android: Gridview show more items by button click

Tags: android, gridview, paging

I want to create a grid view like this. (sorry it's a bit messy, not good in drawing :D)
[image: sorry it's a bit messy]
so basically gridview will show the 1st - 4th item. and if I click next, the 5th-8th items will show up.. and so on.

My current idea is to set a gridview with 4 items and change the adapter in every button click. But I think it's not really convenient. Another idea is to use 'paging'..

Thank you!

Comment: You can use _ViewPager_

Comment: this may help you http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/09/01/faster-loading-images-gridviews-listviews-android-menory-caching-complete-implemenation-sample-code/

Answer (score 0):

You can use horizontal scroll view containing a linear layout and add your griditem(view) in linearlayout dynamically.
Let me know if you still need help in this idea!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, use RecyclerView with horizontal LinearLayoutManager.. However, user will be able to scroll through the items as well. To disable scrolling on a RecyclerView, you can subclass it and override onTouchEvent() method, which will disable any reaction to MOVE event:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch(event.getAction()){

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break; //Don't call super.

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    return false;
}
```

When the user clicks the button to move to next page, you can use one of the following methods on the `LinearLayoutManager` object to find the current position within the adapter:

```
int findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

When you have determined the new position, you can scroll to new data with either `scrollToPosition()` or `smoothScrollToPosition()` methods..